# VBA & Triggering an Automatic Calculation

Tags: excel, vba

Does setting calculation mode to Automatic via VBA trigger a calculation?

I'm working on an inherited project at work and am looking at ways to speed it up. These two lines are near the close of the macro. Is this causing the book to calculate twice? Would I accomplish a single calculation by omitting the first calculate or is this necessary?

```
Calculate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: If you do Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the top of the code and then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end this should solve your question. It does calculate after turning it to Manual and then back to Automatic

Comment: @Ethan, we do have Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the beginning of the macro. So you are confirming that we are calculating twice at the end of our macro by having the above? I can get rid of the lone Calculate and it will only calculate once when we Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You are calculating twice.

Comment: Thanks, @Ethan. I'm new here - why not post this as answer and I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the top of the code and then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end this calculates once. To answer your question, yes you are calculating twice when including Application.Calculate